# SQL data to JSON file

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a question for you stackoverflow experts :).  I'm planning to use the FLOT jQuery plugin to chart some data to the MVC3 application I'm building.

I have several views that return data, but I'm just using a resultset and not an entity framework of any sort (it's nice and fast).  I've never worked with JSON before, and I have the following questions:

a) Do I have to use a data model to return data to the controller, then use the JSON method to create the JSON file, or can I return the data without using an entity framework and achieve the same result?
b) Is there a bit of sample code anywhere that can help me out with this (or a link to a good example?

Many thanks in advance ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get your data into a class with properties (get;set;) then you can simply use the built in serializer for MVC ie return Json(yourClass);

If you want a bit more control over it, check out
http://json.codeplex.com/

Theres a linq-to-json and a dataset converter as well.

Comment: thanks for your response.  What is the best practice around this?  Is it theoretically "OK" for lack of a better word, to park the code inside the view page, or do I break it up into Model and Controller as well?

Please forgive the newb question, my depth of experience with MVC is about two weeks :).

Comment: No, it its not ok.  You want to fetch the dataset in your controller, use the techniques adam explained to create the model, and then pass the model to the view.